# Nested counts from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 tables.

Employee

```
EMPID License  Experience  Salary
----  ------  ----------  ------
ABC1  3256     5 years     $1000
ABC2  1324     10 years    $3000
ABC3  2345     11 years    $2500
```

Machine_Control

```
MID   MCODE OPRID   SMID   SMCODE  MLOCATION
-------------------------------------------
M1     1     ABC1      NULL    NULL   LOCATION1
M1     2     ABC2      NULL    NULL   LOCATION2
M1     3     NULL      M1      1      LOCATION1
M1     4     ABC1      NULL    NULL   LOCATION3
M1     5     NULL      M1      2      LOCATION2
```

Looking for the following output. Note that both primary (MID,MCODE) and secondary (SMID, SMCODE) should be counted for no_machines and No_locations for a given EMPID. MID and MCODE are primary key of the table.

```
EMPID  License Experience No_Machines  No_Locations
--------------------------------------------------
ABC1    3256      5 years     3              2
ABC2    1324      10 years    2              1
ABC3    2345      11 years    0              0
```

I tried the following

```
select a.EMPID, a.Licesne, a.Experience, count(b.MID) No_Machines, count(distinct b.MLOCATION) No_Locations
from Employee a
    left join Machine_Control b on a.EMPID= b.OPRDID
group by a.EMPID;
```

I'm getting the following results

```
EMPID  License Experience No_Machines  No_Locations
--------------------------------------------------
ABC1    3256      5 years     2              2
ABC2    1324      10 years    1              1
ABC3    2345      11 years    0              0
```

Comment: Difficult to read and there's no question at all.

Comment: sorry new to the site and formatting was messed up. I guess I fixed it now to a more readable format.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! this is half way to [mcve], but i can't quite grasp the numbers in the "expected output." am i missing some important clue..? i meant, that `No_Machines` in the result, why is it `3` for `ABC1`? does null for `LOCATION1` also considered?

Comment: also, is your `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the results of getting SMID and SMCODE with UNION ALL.

```sql
SELECT
  a.EMPID, a.License, a.Experience,
  COALESCE(b.No_Machines, 0) No_Machines,
  COALESCE(b.No_Locations, 0) No_Locations
FROM Employee a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT OPRID,
      COUNT(MID) No_Machines,
      COUNT(distinct MLOCATION) No_Locations
    FROM (
      SELECT MID, MCODE, OPRID, MLOCATION
        FROM Machine_Control
      UNION ALL
      SELECT s.SMID, s.SMCODE, p.OPRID, p.MLOCATION
        FROM Machine_Control s JOIN Machine_Control p
        ON s.SMID=p.MID AND s.SMCODE=p.MCODE
      ) ps
    GROUP BY OPRID) b
  ON a.EMPID= b.OPRID
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PXVT9dBGHMovRNXT7ruP9/0)

Comment: isn't your query returns `No_Machine` as `2` for `ABC1`? guess i'm reading the question the wrong way, lol.